# How to use Extjs4 save() in php server?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, extjs4

When calling model.save(), in chrome it shows it is sending Request Payload parameters. I do not know what the heck it is, cannot find any reference on the net, and do not know how to use it on server.

Using $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST in server side does not show anything... Can anyone show me how to use that Request Payload?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this :

```
$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's posted in the request body, not query args. Don't know php, so can't help more than that.